# android children inside relativelayout same height

Tags: android, android-layout

I want two Views inside a RelativeLayout with the same height one below the other.
I can't use LinearLayout's **weight** so I have to figure out another way to do it.

From what I googled and read on SO I found out as a solution to use an anchor View centerHorizontal in the parent View and place the 2 children one above and one below that anchor View, but it doesn't seems to work.

My code so far is :

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="top" >

        <View android:id="@+id/anchor"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#000"/>


            <RelativeLayout 
                 android:id="@+id/toplayout"                    
                 android:background="#990000"                   
                 android:layout_above="@+id/anchor"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/anchor">

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
                    android:layout_width="218dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           </RelativeLayout>        


   </RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a mistake to my code or the way I'm trying to solve it is wrong from the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but by the Anchor View, you set its layout to be Central Horizontal, but it should be Central Vertical. Also, you can use Align Top and Bottom to match the Views' edges.

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#990000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_above="@+id/anchor">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#000"/>
    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/anchor" >

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
            android:layout_width="218dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```